# Inconsistent output on leetcode and vs code

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

```
class Solution:
    def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int,memo={}) -> int:
        if target in memo:
            return memo[target]
        if target==0:
            return 1
        if target<0:
            return 0
        a=0
        for i in nums:
            a+=self.combinationSum4(nums,target-i,memo)
        memo[target]=a
        return memo[target]
```

This is the code I wrote in Python3 for problem number 377 on leetcode.
The problem is for testcase nums=[9] and target=3, the above code is giving 4 as output while when i ran the same code on vs code the output was 0, which is the desired output.

i dry ran the code several times just in case.
The code is running as expected when I dont use memoization, but when i memoize it gives wrong result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHtqW.png)with memoization
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY2Dq.png)without memoization

to memoize the code I passed memo a dictionary in the arguments, then line 3 and 4 and rather than returning "a" as it is added last two lines

I understand that leetcode runs several test i'm unclear as to why a test case is producing different results for the same piece of code in vscode and leetcode console

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.memo={}
    def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        if target in self.memo:
            return self.memo[target]
        if target==0:
            return 1
        if target<0:
            return 0
        a=0
        for i in nums:
            a+=self.combinationSum4(nums,target-i)
        self.memo[target]=a
        return self.memo[target]
```

i changed the code in this manner and the code works as normal now

Comment: Your `memo` will survive across multiple test cases: not what you want. Instead, make `memo` an instance attribute of `Solution`. As far as I know LeetCode will create a new instance for each test case.

Comment: is leetcode storing items of different test cases in the same memo because of the way my code is structured?

Comment: See the duplicate reference at the top. The default parameter value is only evaluated once and then reused (contrary how other programming languages deal with defaults).

Comment: @trincot thank you for your help, my code works and not only that i learned something new and valuable i really appreciate it